# Flask MongoLab MongoKit

Tags: mongodb, flask, mlab, mongokit

I have the following code, very simple:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask.ext.mongokit import MongoKit, Document
from pymongo import Connection
from pymongo import collection
from pymongo import database
from flask.ext.mongokit import MongoKit, Document
from datetime import datetime
from bson.objectid import ObjectId

app = Flask(__name__)

class data(Document):
    __collection__ = 'xusers'
    __database__ = 'database22'
    structure = {
        'email' : unicode,
        }
app.config['MONGODB_DATABASE'] = 'flask'
app.config['MONGODB_HOST'] = 'localhost' 
app.config['MONGODB_PORT'] = 27017
app.config['MONGODB_USERNAME'] = None
app.config['MONGODB_PASSWORD'] = None   

database22 = MongoKit(app)
database22.register([data])

admin = database22.data()
admin.email = 'admin@admin.com'
```

and keep getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/v2/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_mongokit.py", line 238, in __getattr__
    self.connect()
  File "/Users/v2/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_mongokit.py", line 196, in connect
    host=ctx.app.config.get('MONGODB_HOST'),
```

It's driving me nuts, any help would be really appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: after I run the code

Comment: It's not in the code you provided. Where is it?

Comment: I added it in the question, I run the the server, and the error pops up because of admin = database22.data()